# Groovy console source code!

Tags: groovy

Where i can find Groovy Console source code? I have searched Google a lot but couldn't find it. And I have downloaded the Source code of groovy even, but i couldn't figure out in which folder it is in!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fetch the source archive from http://dist.groovy.codehaus.org/distributions/groovy-src-1.8.0.zip: the console is in there.

EDIT: even easier. https://svn.codehaus.org/groovy/trunk/groovy/groovy-core/src/main/groovy/ui/

Comment: i have already have this downloaded, but can you specify in which folder it is in?